# I can not link the Angular component with one route of my back-end (localhost:3000/list/:page?)

Tags: angular, parameters, routes, angular6, angular7

I have a problem :(.

I want to paginate the information in the database to fill a table that will be shown to the user, I got it and I tried it with Postman:

This is the route in the backend:

```
    router.get('/list/:page?', listarController.listar);
```

This is the function in NodeJS and the query to pull the data

```
    controller.listar = async(request, response) => {
        var page = request.query.page;
        try {
            const result = await pool.query('SELECT * FROM "TP_DETALLE_DENUNCIA" LIMIT 10 OFFSET ' + (page * 10));
            return response.status(200).send({ data: result.rows });
        } catch (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
    };
    module.exports = controller;`
```

This would be the route for page # 1: (Rows 1-10):
        `localhost:3000/list/?page = 0`

(Rows 11-20):
        `localhost:3000/list/?page = 1`

**This works in Postman!**

[image: ![Backend working fine!]

But I can not link it with angular to show the data to the user. The idea is create a button "next" that increments the value of page in 1 and another button "previous" that decrements the page in 1.

This is my service class who has the method that connect to nodejs

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { DenunciaAnonima } from '../models/denunciaAnonima';
import { Global } from '../services/global';

@Injectable()
export class DenunciaService {
    public url: string;

    constructor(
        private _http: HttpClient
    ) {
        this.url = Global.url;
    }
    testService() {
        return 'Probando el servicio de Angular';
    }

    listarDenuncias(page): Observable<any> {
        let headers = new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type','application/json');
        return this._http.get(this.url + 'list/' + page, { headers: headers });
    }
}
}
```

the HTML of this component:

```
<div class="container">
    <input type="button" value="Next" (click)="nextPage();">
</div>
```

This is the component.ts of the component who will show the data to the users:

```
import { Component, OnDestroy, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { DenunciaAnonima } from '../../models/denunciaAnonima';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';
import { DenunciaService } from '../../services/denunciaService';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute, Params } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-list',
  templateUrl: './list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./list.component.css'],
  providers: [DenunciaService]
})
export class ListComponent implements OnInit {
  public page: number;
  public denuncias: DenunciaAnonima[];
  constructor(
    private _denunciaService: DenunciaService,
    private _router: Router,
    private _route: ActivatedRoute
  ) {
    this.page = 0;
  }

  ngOnInit() {}
      this.nextPage();
  }

  nextPage() {
    this._denunciaService.listarDenuncias(this.page).subscribe(response => {
      this.denuncias = response.data;
    },
      error => {
        console.log(<any>error);
      });
    this.page = this.page + 1;
  }
}
```

Finally the Routes of Angular:

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
    { path: '', component: HomeComponent },
    { path: 'registros/:id', component: ListComponent } },
    { path: '**', component: ErrorComponent },
];
```

I'm worried please if someone has any suggestion, That would be great! 
Thanks to everyone

Answer (score 0):

You will have use HttpParams.
refer to: https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpParams

`let params = new HttpParams().set('page', 1);`

and you can pass them through your get request as

`this._http.get(this.url + 'list/', { params: params });`